# SQL schema and queries to select from permutations of columns efficently

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, database-schema

I'm working with postgresql 9.3+

I'm designing a DB to describe statistics of a group of peoples.
Imagine you had 150 players to pick from, teams by 5 and data about every possible team combination( number of points per match, match length, etc..). Each team member can have different positions ( like point guard, shooting guard, small forward, etc..).

Currently it only contains one table which looks like this

(p id the ID of the player, R is the role)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  id       |  p1 | r1 | p2 | r2 | p3 | r3 | p4 | r4 | p5 | r5 | data columns |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1A2C5A8D9B |  1  |  A |  2 |  C | 5  | A  | 8  | D  | 9  | B  | ............. |
```

px are sorted and can have ~150 values (not contiguous)

```
p1 < p2 < p3 < p4
```

rx is an enum of 4 possible values,

id is obtained by concatenating  `pxrx for x in 0..5`, it is a string and is the unique key.

The most performed queries will be:

- `find all the rows which have (34, A), (411, D), (233, A)`

  the only way I can think about this is to

  `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id like '%34A%233A%411D%'`
- `sum the data of all the rows which have (34, A), (411, D), (233, A)`

  I can do that with
  `SELECT SUM(data1), SUM(data2) FROM ...;`
- `find which are the missing px which maximize a given data column`

I could do this by

```
`SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY data LIMIT 1`
```

but I would have no way to `find the px which has rx=ROLE which maximizes data`.

- `find avg performances of the team on data for the different roles of p=34`

To do this I would need to group matches by the rx given that px=34 (but in some rows p1=34, in others p4=34), and find the avg of data for each group.

On 80000 rows the first query takes 40ms on my machine and is performed with a sequential scan (like all the others).
The scan produces little matches (in the order of the 100s).
So I'm not able to exploit indexes and the additional columns which provide all the informations.
The rows will grow at least 10 folds, so execution times of about 400ms are definitely a problem.

I will interact with the database from Django ORM.

1. How can I modify the table schema design so that all the queries I wrote would become easy to express in Django and faster to execute (exploiting indexes)?
   I'm populating the DB with data generated from python, so I can perform operations on the data before putting it in the DB
2. If the there doesn't exists a smarter schema, how could I write the last query, which I'm not currently able to write?

Additionally, how would you design the indexes?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form (your {p1,r1} etc are a *repeating group* )

Comment: You are right. I can put them in their own table, and put foreign keys instead of the groups.
How do you think that would help in the problems previously specified? I still wouldn't know in which position they are